# RLMArray to RLMLinkingObjects migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, realm-migration

I have a model with two objects: `SFCHChat` and `SFCHMessages` which have a one-to-many relationship.

Due to an upgrade from Realm 0.98 to 2.0 I now get the following exception in production:

```
Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'SFCHChat.chatId' has been made optional. - Property 'SFCHChat.lastReadedMessageId' has been made optional. - Property 'SFCHMessage.chat' has been added. - Property 'SFCHMessage.messageId' has been made optional. - Property 'SFCHMessage.chatId' has been made optional. - Property 'SFCHMessage.userId' has been made optional. - Property 'SFCHMessage.message' has been made optional. - Property 'SFCHUser.initials' has been made optional. - Property 'SFCHUser.userId' has been made optional. - Property 'SFCHChat.messages' has been removed.
```

So, I've added optionals to `+ (NSArray *)requiredProperties`, but it's not clear how to go about `SFCHChat.messages` and `SFCHMessage.chat`. Here is the code diff for those objects:

```
### SFCHMessage.h
-@property (readonly) SFCHChat *chat;
+@property SFCHChat *chat;

### SFCHMessage.m
-- (SFCHChat *)chat
-{
-    return [[self linkingObjectsOfClass:@"SFCHChat" forProperty:@"messages"] firstObject];
-}
-

### SFCHChat.h

-@property RLMArray<SFCHMessage> *messages;
+@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *messages;

### SFCHChat.m

++ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties {
+    return @{
+             @"messages": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:SFCHMessage.class propertyName:@"chat"],
+             };
+}
+
```

To summarize I migrated an array on Realm objects to a `RLMLinkingObjects` property, as `linkingObjectsOfClass` became deprecated. So, instead of adding `SFCHMessage` objects to `SFCHChat.messages` RLMArray I added a `chat` property to every `SFCHMessage`, and link back from them with `RLMLinkingObjects`.

It looks like changing to `(readonly)` is treated as removing properties in realm, whereas removing it is treated as adding properties. Do I actually need a migration block for my case? How would I perform this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd say it'd be appropriate for you to bump your Realm's schema and run a migration.

While you can mitigate when Realm added optional values to all properties by simply explicitly making them required, when it comes to adding or removing properties, that will simply require a migration.

Unless there's data in the properties that will be lost in the migration unless you choose to preserve them, running a Realm migration is as easy as simply adding an empty block.

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *configuration = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
configuration.schemaVersion = 1; //Must be incremented by 1 each time the schema is changed.
configuration.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) { };
[RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:configuration];
```

This will make it that the next time you call `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]`, the migration will be run and your file will be upgraded.